# compiling cocos2dx game for windows 64 bit

Tags: cocos2d-x

people,
I’ve been working on a cocos2dx game project, which is quite big. This game runs very fine on MacOS ( I5 processor), My old Ipad2, and a lot of middle ends android devices.

Unfortunately, I’m experiencing very serious performance issues on Windows 64. I have compiled the game for Win32.
I’m very worried that those performance issues have their origin on the 32bit limitations. It is true that Windows 64 is compatible with 32-bit software, but I also know that it is not the same thing as native 32-bit in several cases. Generally speaking, native 64-bit software is faster than native 32-bit software, and I’m almost sure that 32-bit apps running on 64 bit OS have to deal with one extra layer of abstraction or adaptations.

Most of the time, converting software from 32 to 64 bit is as easy as flipping a directive on the Visual Studio project. But it seems not to be the case on Cocos2dX.

I tried to change the win32 project changing the target to x64, but It resulted in an avalanche of linker errors on libcocos2d module. the other modules compiled correctly, including the game exe.

I’m still working on this problem in the hope that I could test if the performance issues can be fixed in 64 bit. And it is also good to have my software running with a full 64-bit compatibility.

Comment: I don't think there is anything within the Cocos2d-x codebase itself which would stop it running on 64-bit, as it already does on mac and 64-bit iOS, but it's the thirdparty libraries which are the issue.  I don't think anyone cares enough about 64-bit Windows to do the work required to generate the 64-bit libraries.